# XMPP chat using node js and Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, xmpp

This code gets a message from an XMPP server and logs it to the console:

```
connection.on('online', function(data) {

    connection.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
        var body = stanza.getChild('body');
        var message = body.getText();

        console.log('with out socket: ', message);

    });
});
```

This displays the message in the console, but how can I send this message for display on the HTML page?

I'm using Angular JS.

Comment: I have solve this problem myself .I have use socket.io that read my message and thus i can get these message on my html pages